# Datetime Format Setting In SSRS

Tags: reportingservices-2005

We have a requirement where date time values would be passed to the report parameter which is of "String" date type (and not "DateTime"). The report parameter would be a queried one i.e. it would have a list of values in which the passed value should fall in.

The strange part is that if the date time value passed to this parameter is passed in this format mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM then only it succeeds otherwise a error is displayed (If month/date/hour/minute/second is having a single digit value then we need to pass single digit value to parameter as well).

Assuming that the report server picks this format from the "regional settings" in control panel, we tried modifying the date & time formats as yyyy-mm-dd & HH:mm:ss but the outcome was the same.

On researching more I found some suggestions specifying to change the language property in the rdl (I was not able to figure out how) but this would not be the solution I am looking for. I also found another topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763869?tab=oldest#tab-top) but it didn't provide the solution we are looking for. 
I need to understand if this format is controlled at the report server level & is it configurable. It would be great if someone can provide some guidance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Format(,"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM ")

Then it doesn't matter what the regional settings are.